# Fill Empty Panda Dataframe Using Loop Method

Tags: pandas, loops

I am currently working with some telematics data where the trip id is missing. Trip id is unique. 1 trip id contains multiple of rows of data consisting i.e gps coordinate, temp, voltage, rpm, timestamp, engine status (on or off). The data pattern indicate time of engine status on and off, can be cluster as a unique trip id. Though, I have difficulty to translate the above logic in order to generate these tripId.

Tried to use few pandas loop methods but keep failing.

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'Ignition_Status':'ON', 'tripID':''},{'Ignition_Status':'ON','tripID':''},
       {'Ignition_Status':'ON', 'tripID':''},{'Ignition_Status':'OFF','tripID':''},
       {'Ignition_Status':'ON', 'tripID':''},{'Ignition_Status':'ON','tripID':''},
       {'Ignition_Status':'ON', 'tripID':''},{'Ignition_Status':'ON', 'tripID':''},
       {'Ignition_Status':'ON', 'tripID':''},{'Ignition_Status':'OFF', 'tripID':''},
       {'Ignition_Status':'ON', 'tripID':''},{'Ignition_Status':'OFF', 'tripID':''}]

test = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print (test)
```

**Approach Taken**

```
n=1

for index, row in test.iterrows():
test['tripID']=np.where(test['Ignition_Status']=='ON',n,n)
n=n+1
```

**Expected Result**

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`series.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to check for `OFF` and [`series.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`series.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
test=test.assign(tripID=test.Ignition_Status.eq('OFF')
                    .shift(fill_value=False).cumsum().add(1))
```

---

```
   Ignition_Status  tripID
0               ON       1
1               ON       1
2               ON       1
3              OFF       1
4               ON       2
5               ON       2
6               ON       2
7               ON       2
8               ON       2
9              OFF       2
10              ON       3
11             OFF       3
```

Comment: will try this code later in my working df and will let you know the outcome

Comment: @anky_91, I get: TypeError: shift() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'

Comment: @adhg what is the version of pandas `pd.__version__` ? you can also use `.shift().fillna(False)` for lower versions

Comment: @adhg I meant pandas version, for lower versions use `test=test.assign(tripID=test.Ignition_Status.eq('OFF').shift().fillna(False).cumsum().add(1))`

Comment: thanks @anky_91 , the code also work in my working df